# Maze solve and shortest path with Java BFS

Tags: java, breadth-first-search, maze

The goal is to draw a maze after resolving it (using BFS) with the shortest path from start to exit.

**OUTPUT must be like this**

```
***************************************************
[20,19]
***************************************************
#####################
..#...........#.....#
#.#.#########.#.###.#
#...#.........#.#...#
###############.#.###
#.....#.......#.#...#
#.#######.###.#.#.#.#
#...#...#...#...#.#.#
###.###.###.###.#.#.#
#.#.#.#...#.#...#.#.#
#.#.#.#.#1#.#.###.#.#
#...#.#.#1#.#...#.#.#
#####.###1#.#####.###
#.#1111111#.#...#...#
#.#1#######.#.#.###.#
#.#1#...#...#.#.#...#
#.#1###.#.#####.#####
#.#11111111111111111#
#.##.####.#########1#
#..................11
#####################
```

There are many path to go to the exit **[20,19]** , but we must draw with the shortest path.

My code is below but it doesn't print the shortest path.

**CODE**

```
class Maze {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int W = 21;
        int H = 21;
        int X = 9;
        int Y = 10;
        String[] mazeString = {
            "##########.##########",
            "..#...........#.....#",
            "#.#.#########.#.###.#",
            "#...#.........#.#...#",
            "###############.#.###",
            "#.....#.......#.#...#",
            "#.#######.###.#.#.#.#",
            "#...#...#...#...#.#..",
            "###.###.###.###.#.#.#",
            "#.#.#.#...#.#...#.#.#",
            "#.#.#.#.#.#.#.###.#.#",
            "#...#.#.#.#.#...#.#.#",
            "#####.###.#.#####.###",
            "#.#.......#.#...#...#",
            "#.#.#######.#.#.###.#",
            "#.#.#...#...#.#.#...#",
            "#.#.###.#.#####.#####",
            "#.#.................#",
            "#.##.####.#########.#",
            "#.........#..........",
            "####.######.#########"
        };
        Node[][] nodes = new Node[W][H];
        Node start = null;
        List<Node> result = new ArrayList<>();
        Boolean[][] visited = new Boolean[W][H];
        Boolean[][] blocked = new Boolean[W][H];
        Boolean[][] exits = new Boolean[W][H];
        for (int i = 0; i < H; i++) {
            String R = mazeString[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < W; j++) {
                Node node = new Node(j, i);
                blocked[j][i] = R.charAt(j) == '#';
                node.blocked = R.charAt(j) == '#';
                exits[j][i] = (!node.blocked) && (i == (H - 1) || j == (W - 1) || i == 0 || j == 0);
                visited[j][i] = false;
                node.exit = (!node.blocked) && (i == (H - 1) || j == (W - 1) || i == 0 || j == 0);
                nodes[j][i] = node;
                if (X == j && Y == i) {
                    start = nodes[j][i];
                }
            }
        }
        List<List<Node>> paths = new ArrayList<>();
        findExits(start, nodes, visited, W, H, result, paths);
        if (!result.isEmpty()) {
            Collections.sort(result, new Comparator<Node>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Node o1, Node o2) {
                    if (Integer.compare(o1.x, o2.x) == 0) {
                        return Integer.compare(o1.y, o2.y);
                    } else {
                        return Integer.compare(o1.x, o2.x);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        for (List<Node> path : paths) {
            System.out.println("***************************************************");
            System.out.println("[" + path.get(0).x + "," + path.get(0).y + "]");
            System.out.println("***************************************************");
            for (int i = 0; i < H; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < W; j++) {
                    String s = blocked[j][i] ? "#" : path.contains(new Node(j, i)) ? "1" : ".";
                    System.out.print(s);
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void findExits(Node start, Node[][] nodes, Boolean[][] visited, int W, int H, List<Node> result, List<List<Node>> paths) {
        int x = start.x;
        int y = start.y;
        visited[x][y] = true;
        if (start.exit) {
            result.add(start);
            visited[x][y] = false;
            List<Node> path = new ArrayList<Node>();
            while (start.parent != null) {
                path.add(start);
                start = start.parent;
            }
            path.add(start);
            paths.add(path);
        }
        //TOP
        if ((y - 1) >= 0) {
            if (!visited[x][y - 1] && (!nodes[x][y - 1].blocked)) {
                nodes[x][y - 1].parent = start;
                findExits(nodes[x][y - 1], nodes, visited, W, H, result, paths);
            }
        }
        //BOT
        if ((y + 1) < H) {
            if (!visited[x][y + 1] && (!nodes[x][y + 1].blocked)) {
                nodes[x][y + 1].parent = start;
                findExits(nodes[x][y + 1], nodes, visited, W, H, result, paths);
            }
        }
        //LEFT
        if ((x - 1) >= 0) {
            if (!visited[x - 1][y] && (!nodes[x - 1][y].blocked)) {
                nodes[x - 1][y].parent = start;
                findExits(nodes[x - 1][y], nodes, visited, W, H, result, paths);
            }
        }
        //RIGHT
        if ((x + 1) < W) {
            if (!visited[x + 1][y] && (!nodes[x + 1][y].blocked)) {
                nodes[x + 1][y].parent = start;
                findExits(nodes[x + 1][y], nodes, visited, W, H, result, paths);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Node {

        public int x, y;
        boolean blocked = false;
        boolean exit = false;
        Node parent = null;

        public Node(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (obj == null) {
                return false;
            }
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
                return false;
            }
            final Node other = (Node) obj;
            if (this.x != other.x) {
                return false;
            }
            if (this.y != other.y) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

**I want to solve a maze and print the shortest path from start to exit usign BFS. I already solve the maze but my code doesnt print the shortest path, this is my problem.**

**NB (Additional informations, not questions) :**

- the maze can have many exit
- W (width), H (height), [X,Y] (start point)
- '#' (blocked cell), '.' (free cell)
- the path from start and exit is represented by '11111...' on the output

Comment: I would guess that the shortest path has the least amount of ones.

Comment: Yes, but the path I found is not the shortest!

Comment: To make it easier to help you, make it an [mcve] by adding test data. Use `String[][]` for maze data input, instead of scanner.

Comment: Question edited

Comment: You are using `node.blocked` in  `exits[j][i] = (!node.blocked)` but assign a value to it by `node.blocked = R.charAt(j) == '#';` only after using it . Is that correct ?

Comment: Code edited and retested but the result doesnt change. exists array is unused also for that context, but YES it was an error

Comment: I didn't expect it to fix the pass. Just to make sure I understand what you do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please review the following code. It lets you printout all paths found, as well as the shortest one ***found***. 
I did not change nor checked the search algorithm. I think it needs more work because I think it does not find the shortest path possible to each exit. I will look into it later. 
I did not figure out yet what is the use of `List<Node> result`. Also I did not see you implement backtracking.

```
class Maze {

    private static char NUMBER_SIGN = '#', DOT = '.', START = 'S';
    private static char EXIT = 'E', PATH = '1';
    private static Node[][] nodes;
    private static Node start;
    private static boolean[][] visited; //no need to use Boolean
    //exit holds the same information as Node.blocked. No need to duplicate
    //private static boolean[][] blocked;
    //exit holds the same information as Node.exit. No need to duplicate
    //private static boolean[][] exits;

    private static int mazeWidth, mazeHeight, startH, startW; //use meaningful names
    private static List<List<Node>> paths;

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        mazeWidth = 21;//use meaningful names
        mazeHeight = 21;
        startH = 9; startW = 10;

        String[] mazeData = getMazeData()  ;
        makeMaze(mazeData);
        drawMaze(); //draw maze as built from input data

        List<Node> result = new ArrayList<>();
        paths = new ArrayList<>();

        findExits(start, nodes, visited, mazeWidth, mazeHeight, result, paths);

        if (!result.isEmpty()) {
            Collections.sort(result, new Comparator<Node>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Node o1, Node o2) {
                    if (Integer.compare(o1.x, o2.x) == 0) {
                        return Integer.compare(o1.y, o2.y);
                    } else {
                        return Integer.compare(o1.x, o2.x);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        drawAllPaths(); // see all paths found
        List<Node> shortestPath = getShortestPath();
        drawShortestPath(shortestPath);
    }

    private static void drawMaze() {

        System.out.println("***************************************************");
        System.out.println("Maze as defined by input");
        System.out.println("***************************************************");
        drawMaze(null);
    }

    private static void drawAllPaths() {

        for (List<Node> path : paths) {
            System.out.println("***************************************************");
            System.out.println("Path to exit ["
            + path.get(0).x + "," + path.get(0).y + "] length:"+ path.size());
            System.out.println("***************************************************");
            drawMaze(path);
        }
    }

    private static void drawShortestPath(List<Node> path) {

        System.out.println("***************************************************");
        System.out.println("Shortest path is to exit ["
        + path.get(0).x + "," + path.get(0).y + "] length:"+ path.size());
        System.out.println("***************************************************");
        drawMaze(path);
    }

    private static void drawMaze(List<Node> path) {

        for(Node[] row : nodes ) {

            for(Node node : row) {

                char c = node.getGraphics();
                if ((path != null) && path.contains(node)) {c = PATH;}
                System.out.print(c);
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

    private static void makeMaze(String[] mazeData) {

        nodes = new Node[mazeHeight][mazeWidth];
        visited = new boolean[mazeHeight][mazeWidth];

        for (int height = 0; height < mazeHeight; height++) {
            String row = mazeData[height];
            for (int width = 0; width < mazeWidth; width++) {
                Node node = new Node(height, width);
                node.blocked = row.charAt(width) == NUMBER_SIGN;
                visited[width][height] = false;
                node.exit = (!node.blocked) && ((height == (mazeHeight - 1)) ||
                                (width == (mazeWidth - 1)) || (height == 0) || (width == 0));
                nodes[height][width] = node;
            }
        }
        start = nodes[startH][startW];//no need to set it in the loop
    }

    //use boolean instead of Boolean
    private static void findExits(Node start, Node[][] nodes,
            boolean[][] visited, int W, int H, List<Node> result, List<List<Node>> paths) {

        int x = start.x;
        int y = start.y;
        visited[x][y] = true;
        if (start.exit) {
            result.add(start);
            visited[x][y] = false;
            List<Node> path = new ArrayList<>();
            while (start.parent != null) {
                path.add(start);
                start = start.parent;
            }
            path.add(start);
            paths.add(path);
        }
        //TOP
        if ((y - 1) >= 0) {
            if (!visited[x][y - 1] && (!nodes[x][y - 1].blocked)) {
                nodes[x][y - 1].parent = start;
                findExits(nodes[x][y - 1], nodes, visited, W, H, result, paths);
            }
        }
        //BOT
        if ((y + 1) < H) {
            if (!visited[x][y + 1] && (!nodes[x][y + 1].blocked)) {
                nodes[x][y + 1].parent = start;
                findExits(nodes[x][y + 1], nodes, visited, W, H, result, paths);
            }
        }
        //LEFT
        if ((x - 1) >= 0) {
            if (!visited[x - 1][y] && (!nodes[x - 1][y].blocked)) {
                nodes[x - 1][y].parent = start;
                findExits(nodes[x - 1][y], nodes, visited, W, H, result, paths);
            }
        }
        //RIGHT
        if ((x + 1) < W) {
            if (!visited[x + 1][y] && (!nodes[x + 1][y].blocked)) {
                nodes[x + 1][y].parent = start;
                findExits(nodes[x + 1][y], nodes, visited, W, H, result, paths);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Node {

        public int x, y;
        boolean blocked = false;
        boolean exit = false;
        Node parent = null;

        public Node(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (obj == null) {
                return false;
            }
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
                return false;
            }
            final Node other = (Node) obj;
            if (x != other.x) {
                return false;
            }
            if (y != other.y) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        //it is simpler to have Node return its graphic representation
        char getGraphics() {

            char c = blocked ? NUMBER_SIGN : DOT;
            if(equals(start)) { c=START;}
            else if (exit) { c=EXIT;}

            return c;
        }
    }

    private static List<Node> getShortestPath() {
        //initialize with an arbitrary path
        List<Node> shortest = paths.get(0);
        for (List<Node> path : paths) {
            if(path.size() < shortest.size()) {
                shortest = path;
            }
        }
        return shortest;
    }

    private static String[] getMazeData() {

        return  new String[] {
                "##########.##########",
                "..#...........#.....#",
                "#.#.#########.#.###.#",
                "#...#.........#.#...#",
                "###############.#.###",
                "#.....#.......#.#...#",
                "#.#######.###.#.#.#.#",
                "#...#...#...#...#.#..",
                "###.###.###.###.#.#.#",
                "#.#.#.#...#.#...#.#.#",
                "#.#.#.#.#.#.#.###.#.#",
                "#...#.#.#.#.#...#.#.#",
                "#####.###.#.#####.###",
                "#.#.......#.#...#...#",
                "#.#.#######.#.#.###.#",
                "#.#.#...#...#.#.#...#",
                "#.#.###.#.#####.#####",
                "#.#.................#",
                "#.##.####.#########.#",
                "#.........#..........",
                "####.######.#########"
                };
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
An improved version. Please test carefully.

```
class Maze {

    private static char NUMBER_SIGN = '#', DOT = '.', START = 'S';
    private static char EXIT = 'E', PATH = '1';
    private static Node[][] nodes;
    private static Node startNode;
    private static boolean[][] visited; //no need to use Boolean
    //exit holds the same information as Node.blocked. No need to duplicate
    //private static boolean[][] blocked;
    //exit holds the same information as Node.exit. No need to duplicate
    //private static boolean[][] exits;

    private static int mazeRows, mazeCols, startRow, startCol; //use meaningful names
    private static List<List<Node>> paths;

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        mazeCols = 21; mazeRows = 21;//use meaningful and consistent names
        startRow = 9; startCol = 10;        //better keep h,w or height,width all over

        String[] mazeData = getMazeData()  ;
        makeMaze(mazeData);
        drawMaze(); //draw maze as built from input data
        paths = new ArrayList<>();
        findExits(startNode);
        drawAllPaths(); // print all paths found
        List<Node> shortestPath = getShortestPath();
        drawShortestPath(shortestPath);
    }

    private static void drawMaze() {

        System.out.println("*****************************************");
        System.out.println("Maze as defined by input");
        System.out.println("*****************************************");
        drawMaze(null);
    }

    private static void drawAllPaths() {

        for (List<Node> path : paths) {
            System.out.println("*****************************************");
            System.out.println("Path to exit ["
                    + path.get(0).row + "," + path.get(0).col + "] length:"+ path.size());
            System.out.println("*****************************************");
            drawMaze(path);
        }
    }

    private static void drawShortestPath(List<Node> path) {

        System.out.println("*****************************************");
        System.out.println("Shortest path is to exit ["
                + path.get(0).row + "," + path.get(0).col + "] length:"+ path.size());
        System.out.println("*****************************************");
        drawMaze(path);
    }

    private static void drawMaze(List<Node> path) {

        for(Node[] row : nodes ) {
            for(Node node : row) {
                char c = node.getGraphics();
                //overwrite c if node is in path
                if ( (c != EXIT) && ( c != START ) &&
                        (path != null) && path.contains(node)) {c = PATH;}
                System.out.print(c);
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

    private static void makeMaze(String[] mazeData) {

        nodes = new Node[mazeRows][mazeCols];
        visited = new boolean[mazeRows][mazeCols];

        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < mazeRows; rowIndex++) {
            String row = mazeData[rowIndex];
            for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < mazeCols; colIndex++) {
                Node node = new Node(rowIndex, colIndex);
                node.blocked = row.charAt(colIndex) == NUMBER_SIGN;
                visited[rowIndex][colIndex] = false;
                node.exit = (!node.blocked) && ((rowIndex == (mazeRows - 1)) ||
                        (colIndex == (mazeCols - 1)) || (rowIndex == 0) || (colIndex == 0));
                nodes[rowIndex][colIndex] = node;
            }
        }
        startNode = nodes[startRow][startCol];//no need to set it in the loop
    }

    //use boolean instead of Boolean
    private static void findExits(Node node) {

        int row = node.row;
        int col = node.col;

        if(visited[row][col]) { return; }

        if (node.exit) {
            List<Node> path = new ArrayList<>();
            while (node.parent != null) {
                path.add(node);
                node = node.parent;
            }
            path.add(node);
            paths.add(path);
            return; //do not continue to check exit neighbors
        }

        //LEFT
        if ((col - 1) >= 0) {
            Node testNode = nodes[row][col - 1];
            //the following if statement repeats for all directions
            //better put in a method
            if ((testNode.parent == null) && ! testNode.blocked) {
                testNode.parent = node; //parent ! null indicates that cell is tested
                findExits(testNode);
                testNode.parent = null; //set back to null: test finished
            }
        }

        //RIGHT
        if ((col + 1) < mazeCols) {
            Node testNode = nodes[row][col + 1];
            if ((testNode.parent == null) && ! testNode.blocked) {
                testNode.parent = node;
                findExits(testNode);
                testNode.parent = null;
            }
        }

        //TOP
        if ((row - 1) >= 0) {
            Node testNode = nodes[row-1][col];
            if ((testNode.parent == null) && ! testNode.blocked) {
                testNode.parent = node;
                findExits(testNode);
                testNode.parent = null;
            }
        }

        //BOTTOM
        if ((row + 1) < mazeRows) {
            Node testNode = nodes[row+1][col];
            if ((testNode.parent == null) && ! testNode.blocked) {
                testNode.parent = node;
                findExits(testNode);
                testNode.parent = null;
            }
        }

        visited[row][col] = true; //mark as visited after all directions explored
        node.parent = null;
    }

    public static class Node {

        public int row, col;
        boolean blocked = false;
        boolean exit = false;
        Node parent = null;

        public Node(int row, int col) {
            this.row = row;
            this.col = col;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (obj == null) {
                return false;
            }
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
                return false;
            }
            final Node other = (Node) obj;
            if (row != other.row) {
                return false;
            }
            if (col != other.col) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        //it is simpler to have Node return its graphic representation
        char getGraphics() {

            char c = blocked ? NUMBER_SIGN : DOT;
            if(equals(startNode)) { c=START;}
            else if (exit) { c=EXIT;}

            return c;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {

            return "Node " + row +"-"+ col +" ("+ getGraphics() + ")";
        }
    }

    private static List<Node> getShortestPath() {
        //initialize with an arbitrary path
        List<Node> shortest = paths.get(0);
        for (List<Node> path : paths) {
            if(path.size() < shortest.size()) {
                shortest = path;
            }
        }
        return shortest;
    }

    private static String[] getMazeData() {

        return  new String[] {
                "##########.##########",
                "..#...........#.....#",
                "#.#.#########.#.###.#",
                "#...#.........#.#...#",
                "###############.#.###",
                "#.....#.......#.#...#",
                "#.#######.###.#.#.#.#",
                "#...#...#...#...#.#..",
                "###.###.###.###.#.#.#",
                "#.#.#.#...#.#...#.#.#",
                "#.#.#.#.#.#.#.###.#.#",
                "#...#.#.#.#.#...#.#.#",
                "#####.###.#.#####.###",
                "#.#.......#.#...#...#",
                "#.#.#######.#.#.###.#",
                "#.#.#...#...#.#.#...#",
                "#.#.###.#.#####.#####",
                "#.#.................#",
                "#.##.####.#########.#",
                "#.........#..........",
                "####.######.#########"
        };
    }
}
```

Feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: Right result for the improved answer, I'll try to understand it!

Comment: When I change the maze data, it doent give me the right shortest path

Comment: I hope it does help you to get what you wanted. I think it works better and able to find the shortest path found.  I assume the algorithm needs debugging. If so, post the data which produces wrong result (maybe as a new question)

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track where you're building a list of paths.
Try this:

- create an empty list of paths
- start at the starting point, create one path with one cell
- look in the four directions and for each cell that is not blocked *and not already included in any of the previous paths* clone your current path, add that new cell to the end and add it to the list of paths
- now loop through all your paths and repeat this progress, checking the four directions from the cell at the tip
- stop building a path when it hits the exit or has no more legitimate moves to make, i.e. dead end
- use the path with the shortest length

Comment: I will try this!