# BFS , DFS LRTA* ALGORITHMS TO FIND THE OPTIMAL PATH

Tags: depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I have to implement a project for my class and is needed to apply breadth first search, depth first search and LRTA* algorithms to find shortest path.I have a grid and i have to travel from the start position to the finish.In this grid there are many ways and every step has a cost, and I have to apply these algorithms.There are some walls that they stop me, grass that costs 2 units and land costs 1 unit.

I want someone to explain how i have to choose every step when applying bfs,dfs and LRTA*.

Comment: The question is too broad. There are many on line resources  [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_solving_algorithm)  [2](https://cs.stanford.edu/people/abisee/gs.pdf)  [3](https://www.redblobgames.com/pathfinding/a-star/introduction.html)  and examples [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46853229/3992939) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49844011/3992939) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51120719/3992939)

Comment: thank you mate, it will help all of them